# hibernate order of insertion

Tags: java, database, hibernate, insert

I have simple 4 tables with structure:

```
Table a - columns: id(generated), x

Table b - columns: id(generated), a_id(fk to a), y

Table c - columns: id(generated), a_id(fk to a), z

Table d - columns: id(generated), b_id(fk to b), c_id(fk to c), w
```

relationships as follows:

```
a->b one-to-many unidirectional;

a->c one-to-many unidirectional;

b->d one-to-many unidirectional;

c->d one-to-many unidirectional;
```

hibernate performs incorrect order of inserts when persisting a:

should be a,b,c,d

does: a,b,d and fails without having generated c_id

How can I enforce the correct order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can force a flush statement after c to have hibernate send it to the db. That is, create and populate a, b, c then flush. Then create d.

Comment: I am looking for a solution with a cascaded em.persist(a). Your suggestion is to do the work manually step-by-step, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. You mean c to a? You gave me an idea to try d with nullable fk's to c and b as now they are not. Will let you know.